# How to look up a value according to percentile of another column

Tags: r

I have a dataset of two columns and n rows. One column is price, the other is quantity. Now I want to restructure the dataset into a 100*2 data frame, such that one column is Quantity, with each row representing 1% of the total quantity; and another is price, the value of price comes from the original dataset. How to restructure? Do I need to define a function?

I think it might be a piecewise-function problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is an example of the original dataset, though the real one has more rows.

```
df <- data.frame(price = c(2,2,rep(3,3),rep(4,4)),
                 quantity = c(rep(1,3),2,3,3,4,5,5))
```

And here is the expected restructured dataset that I want.

```
# Q is an example of every 1% of sum(df$quantity)
expected.df <- data.frame(Q=paste(c(1:100),'%',sep=""),
                          P=c(rep(2,8),rep(3,24),rep(4,68)))
```

Thanks if anyone could help!

Comment: Do not only use images for input.  It means that responders must retype the whole thing. Cut your data down to a reasonable size it it is large and show it in the question the output of dput(X) where X is your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, here I will use the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(price = c(2,2,rep(3,3),rep(4,4)),
                 quantity = c(rep(1,3),2,3,3,4,5,5))
df
```

```
> df
  price quantity
1     2        1
2     2        1
3     3        1
4     3        2
5     3        3
6     4        3
7     4        4
8     4        5
9     4        5
```

```
xx  <- sum(df$quantity)
df1 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Q_perc = cumsum(quantity),
                Q_perc = paste((Q_perc/xx)*100,"%")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-quantity)
```

```
> df1
  price Q_perc
1     2    4 %
2     2    8 %
3     3   12 %
4     3   20 %
5     3   32 %
6     4   44 %
7     4   60 %
8     4   80 %
9     4  100 %
```

Comment: Thanks! What if for every percentile?

Comment: I edited the answer. Please, could you accept my answer? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work